# Jenkins plugin development: Is it ok to copy jelly files and modify them?

Tags: plugins, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I'm trying to develop my first Jenkins plugin and I'm not sure about several issues: 
So far I have a class that creates a new job type. It basically looks just like the FreeStyleProject of Jenkins and it works fine. 
1) Now I would like the plugin to create an additional section on the configuration page of the job (of the new type). I tried adding a config.jelly in the resources package, but it didn't work. Then I copied Jenkins' configure-entries.jelly from resources/hudson/model/Project and added my information here. Is it ok to do it like this? 
2) Furthermore, I want to add something to the project page. I found out that a file called jobMain.jelly can be used for that, but just creating the file in the resources package doesn't change anything. So instead I copied Jenkins' main.jelly from resources/hudson/model/AbstractProject and added something here. Is that ok? It works, but I'm not sure if I can get into trouble later. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you think you could reformat this question so it's not one massive paragraph. That will facilitate a few more answers

Answer (score 2):

**Configuration page**

- First you need a class which extends a descendant of BuildStepCompatibilityLayer (like the Recorder or Builder class).
- Create a `@DataBoundConstructor` for this class
- Create a Descriptor for this class, as inner class
- Example for a class extending the Builder class:

  ```
  package tryBuilder.tryBuilder;

  import org.kohsuke.stapler.DataBoundConstructor;

  import hudson.Extension;
  import hudson.model.AbstractProject;
  import hudson.model.FreeStyleProject;
  import hudson.tasks.BuildStepDescriptor;
  import hudson.tasks.Builder;

  import org.kohsuke.stapler.DataBoundConstructor;

  public class BuilderExample extends Builder {

    @DataBoundConstructor
    public BuilderExample() {
    }

    @Extension
    public static class Descriptor extends BuildStepDescriptor<Builder> {

      @Override
      public boolean isApplicable(Class<? extends AbstractProject> jobType) {
          return FreeStyleProject.class.isAssignableFrom(jobType);
      }

      @Override
      public String getDisplayName() {
          return "BuildstepName";
      }
    }
  }
  ```

The String returned in the method `getDisplayName()` (now "BuildstepName") determines the name of the build step or action in Jenkins.

- Now you need a map in the resources directory with the same name as the class made above.
- Place the config.jelly in that directory
- In Jenkins, go to a job, then to config, next:

  - If the class you made extends a class derived from Builder: Add build step
  - If the class you made extends a class derived form Publisher: Add action after build step
- And select the name you set in the getDisplayName() method
- Now your config.jelly should be visible in this section

**Add to project page**

- Create a class implementing Action (override the necessary methods and give them a value (not null))
- In the created Builder/Publisher class, Override the `getProjectAction(AbstractProject<?, ?> project)` method and return the above created class which implements Action
- Override the `perform(AbstractBuild build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener)' method in the Builder/Publisher class and let it return true
- As it worked there is a link visible in the side panel on the project page
- link a index.jelly to this Action class (in a resource map with the same name as the Action class)
- You will see this page if you click on the link in the side panel
- to show something on the project page itself you need to create a file called floatingBox.jelly (also in the resource map with the name of the Action class)